# Optimal way to search an ArrayList of Integers in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of integers.

Let's say for example an ArrayList with the integers 0,4,7,10

I want now to compare any given integer and see in which position it is on the ArrayList.

So for example, if my integer is 3, it should be between 0 and 4, so the result will be 1.
If my integer is 9 it will be between 7 and 10, so my result will be 3.

Obviously I can loop through the entire ArrayList, like this:

```
    int indexOfItem = 0;
    if (mylist.size()>0)
        while (indexOfItem<mylist.size() && integerImSearching>mylist.get(itemsToSkip)) {
            indexOfItem++;          
        }
```

And I can get the Index of my item from this method.
But while this is fine, if the ArrayList is small, I'm afraid it's not the optimal way if the list is rather large. Is there a better way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your `ArrayList` contents are sorted, you should use [`Collections.binarySearch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29) to locate your item. This will make each search O(log n) instead of O(n).

This function return the index of the item, if found, or else the ones' complement of its insertion position. So, for your purposes, you can do this:

```
int lowerBound(List<Integer> list, int item) {
    int result = Collections.binarySearch(list, item);
    return result >= 0 ? result : ~result;
}
```

Comment: It may not be obvious to everyone that that if binarySearch() does not find the item, it returns the position that your item _would_ be located.

Comment: @John Or rather, its ones' complement.

Comment: Chris are you comparing against 0 for the event that the given value is smaller than all arrayList values ?

Comment: @Lefteris No, the comparison against 0 is to see if the item is an exact match for a value in your `ArrayList` (as opposed to between two values).

Comment: I'm a bit confused now, as the documentation states `Returns:the index of the search key, if it is contained in the list;`, So result will be a positive integer if it's an exact match. Right ?

Comment: @Lefteris It will be non-negative for an exact match, and negative otherwise (such as when between two values).

Comment: OK, now I got it. Thank you Chris